Second monitor lagging with ubuntu 20.04
I’m having a problem that has already made me lose my patience!
The problem is: My second monitor starts lagging after some time of use, specially after a suspend or running demanded tasks like using CUDA for Machine Learning.
This is my setup:

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-122-generic
Nvidia-smi output: nvidia-smi log
NVIDIA Driver: 535.183.01

To troubleshoot this problem, i already tested other drivers but no one solved the problem.
After that, i already re-installed ubuntu and then made “sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall”, which made the graphics driver update from “Using X Org X Server - Nouveay display driver” to the “Nvidia driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-535(proprietaty, tested)”, but this unfortunatelly didn’t solve the problem.
I would appreciate if there’s somebody that can help me to solve the problem!
